# Openpyxl changing a cell value and copying the row below

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I would like to find cells which contain `value1|value2` so that I can remove `|value2` from that cell and make a copy of the row where `value1` was right below it.

For example if a row contains:
`value0 value1 value2 values3|values33 values4` I would then insert a new row below which would be `value0 value1 value2 values33 values4` and the original row would be changed to `value0 value1 value2 values3 values4`.

So far I have managed to find the cells which contain | but do not know how to progress further.

**In conclusion I'd like to know**: How can I edit the cell upon finding the match and copy a row below it with the applied change while also applying a change to the current row so that it no longer contains that value.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('file.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet1']

s = '|'

for row in sheet.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        if s in str(cell.value):
            print(cell.value)
```

Output:

```
value1|value2
value3|value4
...
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, here is a solution using [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html)

```
import pandas as pd
#Read excel file
df = pd.read_excel('duplicate.xlsx')
for c in df.columns:
    #for each column check if it contains required character
    dd = df[df[c].str.contains('|', regex=False)]
    if len(dd) > 0:
        #If contains iterate the rows
        for i, row in dd.iterrows():
            #Split the cell value by character
            vals = row[c].split('|')
            #Check if the resultant list has more than one value
            if len(vals) > 1:
                #Create a new data frame for the number of resultant values
                dd = pd.DataFrame([row]*(len(vals)))
                rows = len(dd)
                roc = 0
                #replace the values
                for v in vals:
                    dd[c].iloc[roc] = v
                    roc += 1
                #append the new dataframe to the main data frame
                df = df.append(dd)
        #Finally remove the rows that contains character from the column in iteration
        df = df[~df[c].str.contains('|', regex=False)]
```

Excel input:

[image]

Output:

[image]